# Как переслать сообщение в другой чат vk с помощью vkbottle

Tags: python, вконтакте

Есть метод messages.send и у его есть параметр forward, при отправке его выдаёт ошибка, что forward некорректен.

Вот структура forward:

```
{"owner_id": message.from_id, "peer_id": message.from_id, \
"conversation_message_ids": [message.conversation_message_id]}
```

Бот на группе.

Answer (score 1):

Такая структура не подойдёт, нужно использовать
`from vkbottle_types.objects import MessagesForward`
И когда передаешь forward аргумент получить JSON с помощью метода MessagesForward.json()